# Imported font issue with widths

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BryantMedium';
    src:url('fonts/bryant-medium-webfont.eot');
    src:url('fonts/bryant-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/bryant-medium-webfont.svg#BryantMedium') format('svg'),
        url('fonts/bryant-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is how I import my fonts, and here is a sample div:

```
<div id="info">
by <span id="name">USERNAME</span> on <span id="date">24 Nov 2013</span>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks in the end:

[image]

For some reason, when the page is reloaded, this does not happen sometimes. But most of the times, this happens. This also does not happen when I use google fonts.

So I'm wondering what is going wrong here? I think there is an issue with page resources being loaded (fonts in this case) but either way this should not be happening... Any ideas?

Comment: i guess you added some width to span elements

Comment: Couldn't find anything called Bryant Medium on Google Fonts. Is there any way you can show us a test page? It looks to me like a browser quirk — I assume this is only happening in one particular browser?

Comment: `@font-face` and HTML syntax looks OK. Post CSS related to `#name` and `#date`.

Comment: Pavlo: #info span{color: #f52f3f;}

Comment: Barney: it's a custom font -- as you can see the font files are imported, so it's not a google font.

Comment: @Zettam wrap `by` and `on` to `span` words as well and see if it fixes

Comment: I was thinking that this is a common thing since whenever I use custom (imported) fonts this issue happens. This is why I decided not to use custom fonts in my earlier project... but for this one, this specific font is essential..

Comment: Morpheus: then they'll all be pink... Also I've tried, did not fix it.

Comment: Keep in mind, `fonts/bryant-medium-webfont.eot` will work only and only when the font directory is in the same directory where the css file is.

Comment: Sonu Joshi: The font is working (the mixed up font is Brynt) - but the spacing is incorrect. For some reason, the width of the spans are 12px.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS affecting the spans?